# Writing data to JSON file using nodeJS takes too long

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

i am creating a function that Count the clicks of elements , and put them in JSON file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = fs.readFileSync('public/js/count.json');
const Words = JSON.parse(file);

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('we are listeining'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({ limit : '1mb' })); 

app.get('/add/:word', addWord);

function addWord(request, response) {
  var data = request.params;
  var word = data.word;
  var reply;
  var found = false;
  for (i = 0; i < Words.length; i++){
    if (Words[i].type == word){
      Words[i].count++;
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }

if (!found) {
  Words.push({"type": word , "count": 1});
}

  var x = JSON.stringify(Words, null, 2);
  fs.writeFile('public/js/count.json', x, finished);

  function finished(){
    console.log('Yay')
  }

    /* 
    console.log(Words[word]); */

/*     response.send(reply); */
  }
```

when i run the code through my script

```
async function counter(elemid){
  let response = await fetch("/add/"+elemid);
}
```

it takes too long to respond , and sometimes it gives request timeout , is there is a faster way to do the exact same purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not writing a response in your finished handler. This is leaving each request to only end via timeout.

In your finished function add `response.end()` at the end.

You can verify that this is working by ensuring that the request receives a 200 response from your server instead of timing out.

Comment: thnx, that helped a alot, there is function that renders the count to some DOM element ``` async function renderCount(clicked) {
   let response = await fetch('js/count.json');
   let data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     if (data[i].type == clicked){
      document.getElementById("lastHandeled").innerText = data[i].type + " " +data[i].count;
     }
   } 
} ``` sometimes when i click the element , it console logs this error script.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at renderCount